# Text size Decreasing when adding external fonts

Tags: android, textview

I had some issues with the default font while displaying Arab, So I added an external font.

Now the letters that are displayed in my app in small for Arab and it's ok for English as I am not using the font for English.
I have made separate layout for tab and phone.

Is there any solution rather than adding the `Textsize` for Arab through java code?

The below is just a sample screenshot.

> image without the font

[image]

> image with external font

[image]

```
AssetManager am = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getAssets();
typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(am, String.format(Locale.US, "fonts/%s", "arabic_font_help_mac_net_49.ttf"));



mBtnBottomLeft.setTypeface(typeface);
mBtnBottomRight.setTypeface(typeface);



 mBtnBottomLeft.setText("ﺷرﻛﺎت اﻟﻧﻘل");
 mBtnBottomRight.setText("مستوردو الآلات "+"والمواد الاولية");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am not getting an answers.
This is not the correct answer but this is how i resolved my problem

I added the font for both English and Arab then increased the text size.
Here I will get the costume style for English as in Arab and not the default font.